# Should I unregister from Publishers/Subscribers when I terminate a ROS node by exiting the script?

Tags: ros, rospy, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

So my question is pretty much what the title is. Is it good practice or even necessary to unregister from ROS publishers or subscribers I used inside my ROS node before terminating the node from the script?

Is there any difference if my ROS node is written in python or c++?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411610/should-i-unregister-from-publishers/subscribers-when-i-terminate-a-ros-node-by-exiting-the-script?/) by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2023-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as my experience is, It does not make difference if you unregistered the pub/sub before terminating the node. As node terminates, it will stop publishing or subscribing to the topic until and unless there is another node publishing or subscribing to the same topic.

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2023-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2